# XCode SwiftUI - Why is my keypad toolbar doing this?

Tags: swiftui

*Very* novice to the app development game. I am trying to put this toolbar above the .decimalPad and I cannot get this large gap to go away.

```
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                .frame(height: 35)
                .overlay {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            isTextFieldFocused = false
                            
                        }) { Text("Done")}
                    }
                    .offset(y: -3)
                    .padding(.trailing)
                }
                .opacity(isTextFieldFocused ? 1 : 0)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) //This makes sure the bottom tab bar stays below the keyboard.
        }
```

[image: Screenshot]

I initially thought it was something in another view causing the spacing, but I managed to parse through the views in the canvas and it does it regardless.

Here is what I'd like it to look like, for reference.
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do7cA.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to be clear on what you want the view to look like when the code is correct.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my post. Sorry everyone, first time on the platform. I promise I'll get better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a `Button` onto your keyboard, you use a `.toolbar` with the locations to `.keyboard` like this:

```
    TextField("Enter Text", text: $text)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                Button(action: {
                     isTextFieldFocused = false
                }) { Text("Done")}
                // If you want it leading, then use a Spacer() after
                Spacer()
            }
        }
```

You were overthinking it by adding the `Rectangle`. This is why we look for minimal reproducible examples. We can dial in the fix for your specific code.

Comment: Ok, this is working! Two questions come up immediately, however: 1. I only added that code under one text field, and it works for all fields automatically. 2. How do I get the "Done" to pad to the left? I'm trying to add it in, and XCode is yelling at me. I don't know why this is giving me so much angst.

Comment: 1. Yes, it does, so you need to think about when you use it. 2. Add a `Spacer()`. See edited code.

Comment: You've just saved me so much stress tonight. I was so mired down in the complicated solution, I looked past the simple. Thank you so much!!